# git checkout between specific tags

Tags: git

is it possible to checkout code from a git repository between specific tags or hash. for example there is tag v1.1 and v1.3. I want to checkout code between these tags or I can use hash number of these two tags. Actually I am looking if i can checkout code from tags or hash, Need code between to points.

Comment: `git checkout v1.1` works just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can supply a hash to `git checkout`:

```
git checkout <hash>
```

If you want to work on code at that point, you should create a branch when doing so:

```
git checkout -b new-branch <hash>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to specify the exact commit you want. Easiest is probably to use some graphic tool like `gitk(1)` to rummage around in the history, and find out the exact commit of interest. Then you can

`git checkout <SHA>`

You have a lot of other ways to specify a commit: by history (e.g. `@~4` is current commit, 4 back through the first parent; by time, `'@{yesterday 10am}'` gives the commit current yesterday at 10am; and several more.